# How to write a listagg on Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For sample data as below,

```
Col1 Col2
1    A
1    B
1    C
2    A
2    B
```

the output I am looking for is

```
COL1 COL2
1    A B C
2    A B
```

This can be done using LISTAGG on Oracle or recursive queries on other DBs but Redshift doesnt support both.

How do I achieve this on Redshift

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I can do if the number of list elements are constant but in my case it was not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to GROUP BY and CONCATENATE fields in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502108/how-to-group-by-and-concatenate-fields-in-redshift)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They just added `LISTAGG()` to Redshift (2015-07-31). http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html

Comment: Note that this doesn't work on System / Catalog tables.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution from another similar question -

```
SELECT col1,
   LISTAGG(col2,', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2)
OVER (PARTITION BY col1) AS EMPLOYEE
FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY col1
```

[This question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502108/how-to-group-by-and-concatenate-fields-in-redshift)

> Redshift has introduced LISTAGG window function that makes it possible to do so now. Here is a quick solution to your problem - may or may not be useful but putting it here so that people will know!

[Here is the documentation about the function.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LISTAGG.html) || [This is the announcement.](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/08/amazon-redshift-now-supports-dynamic-work-load-management-and-list-aggregate-functions/)

Answer (score 2):

Try getting row_number of each group row in a sub query and then on top of the subquery do

```
max(case when row_num_value =1 then col_value end)||','
max(case when row_num_value =2 then col_value end)||','
max(case when row_num_value =3 then col_value end)||.....
```

This is ofcourse a limited version with upper limit upto whatever you chose.

Comment: I thought about this approach and yes it works as long as there is a small number of row_num_values. I am looking at ways to not hard code it plus scale it for a large number of values.

Thanks

Comment: Right now there is no such UDF in Redshift and we are waiting for UDF functionality to be opened by Redshift to do these.

Comment: Considering that LISTAGG() in Redshift doesn't work on System / Catalog tables, I had to use this workaround (assuming <10 rows) and still got the work done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COL1,STRING_AGG(COL2,' ') AS COL2 FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY COL1
```

Comment: This function is not supported in Redshift. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Col1, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(Col2 ORDER BY Col2 ASC), ' ')
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Col1;
```

I don't know what version of PostgreSQL you are using.  Prior to version 8.4, you would have had to define the function `array_agg` before using it:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg (anyelement)
(
    sfunc = array_append,
    stype = anyarray,
    initcond = '{}'
);
```

Comment: I am using Amazon Redshift. It works with Postgres driver 8.1 but it doesn't allow creating functions yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
select
    distinct COL_1,
    listagg(distinct COL_2,
    ',') within group (
    order by COL_2 desc) as my_list
from
    table
group by 1
```

However I have a following question as to how we can retrieve the 2nd element of this list without using substring ( e.g if its an array we can just do array[1])