# Aggregate string values to a list

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, string-aggregation

I am trying to work some very simple logic to transform an unpivoted column into what essentially amounts to a grouped list. However, having troubles doing this efficiently.

Essentially, I have a data set that looks as follows:

```
CUST_ID     ORDER
1           Cake
1           Bread
2           Cake
3           Cake
3           Bread
3           Croissant
4           Croissant
```

But would like to output it as follows:

```
CUST_ID     ORDERS
1           Cake
1           Bread, Cake
3           Cake, Bread, Croissant
4           Croissant
```

I have tried subqueries (which I cannot get to work), but this seems brutal nonetheless:

```
SELECT CUST_ID, SELECT (ORDER FROM table GROUP BY CUST_ID)
FROM table
GROUP BY CUSTT_ID
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where is `CUST_ID = 2`  in desired result?

Comment: @OtoShavadze I think it is a typo.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - yes, it seems.

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Amazon Redshift. Although Redshift is based on (a **very** old version of) Postgres, they are not the same

Comment: Using Redshift, I always believed they were the same variant with only small variations. Thats interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502108/how-to-group-by-and-concatenate-fields-in-redshift), Redshift now has a [`LISTAGG()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LISTAGG.html) analytic function which you can use.

```
SELECT CUST_ID,
       LISTAGG("ORDER", ', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "ORDER")
OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) AS CUST_ID
FROM Table
ORDER BY CUST_ID
```