# Redshift SQL to comma separate a field with group of two fields

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, string-aggregation

[Using the answer from here does NOT WORK, see below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931929/aggregate-string-values-to-a-list)

I want to comma separate a fields values and `GROUP BY` two other fields in Redshift.

Sample data:

```
table_schema table_name column_name 
G1           G2         a
G1           G2         b
G1           G2         c
G1           G2         d
G3           G4         x
G3           G4         y
G3           G4         z
```

Expected Output:

```
table_schema table_name column_name 
G1           G2         a, b, c, d
G3           G4         x, y, z
```

I can do this in MSSQL like so:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + column_name
           FROM your_table b 
           WHERE b.table_schema = a.table_schema AND b.table_name = a.table_name
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM information_schema.tables t
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name AND c.table_schema = t.table_schema
GROUP BY table_schema, table_name
```

And in PostgreSQL this would be:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, String_agg(column_name, ',')
FROM information_schema.tables t
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name AND c.table_schema = t.table_schema
GROUP BY table_schema, table_name
```

But Redshift doesn't contain the `STRING_AGG` function.

I cannot figure out how to do this in Redshift.

**EDIT**

[Using the answer from here does NOT WORK:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931929/aggregate-string-values-to-a-list)

```
SELECT CUST_ID,
       LISTAGG("ORDER", ', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "ORDER")
OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) AS CUST_ID
FROM Table
ORDER BY CUST_ID
```

My Version:

```
SELECT t.table_name, LISTAGG("column_name", ', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "column_name")
OVER (PARTITION BY t.table_name) AS table_schema
FROM information_schema.columns t
ORDER BY t.table_name
```

It gives me the following error:

> 0A000: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Which I don't understand as I am only selecting from a single node?

Comment: What does the INFO message say? Which functions are not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Redshift supports `listagg()` as a window function.  So, you can `join` in the result after a separate aggregation:

```
SELECT t.CUST_ID, c.orders
FROM Table t JOIN
      (SELECT cust_id, LISTAGG("ORDER"::text, ', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "ORDER") as orders
       FROM table t
       GROUP BY cust_id
      ) c
      ON t.cust_id = c.cust_id
ORDER BY CUST_ID;
```

Of course, I see no reason to replicate the data on  each row.  An aggregation query is probably sufficient, so there is only one row per customer in the result set.

Comment: I am getting a different error with this.. `XX000: One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created tables. Examples of user table only functions are LISTAGG, MEDIAN, PERCENTILE_CONT, etc`

Comment: @Matt . . . You may need to cast `"ORDER"` to a string if it is not already a string.

Comment: Not sure where i would do that