# How do I write this Rails ActiveRecord many-to-many query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Jobs` & `Stacks` via `JobStacks`. I'm trying to write an ActiveRecord query to return Jobs containing ALL of the Stacks passed to it.

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :job_stacks
  has_many :stacks, through: :job_stacks
end
```

```
class JobStack < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :stack
end
```

```
class Stack < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_stacks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :jobs, through: :job_stacks
end
```

This creates an SQL `IN` query returning Jobs containing ANY of the stacks.

```
Job.joins(:stacks).where(stacks: {name: ['JavaScript', 'Python']})
```

Is there a similar way to write this returning `Jobs` containing all of the `Stacks` as a `.where` call from `Jobs`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a one method you can use to fetch result with just using DB [STRING_AGG](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/) function

```
Job.joins(:stacks).select("STRING_AGG(stacks.name) AS stack_name").group('stacks.job_id').having("stack_name= 'JavaScript,Python'")
```

There is another method [ARRAY_AGG](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-array_agg-function/), I haven't used that but I think you can try with this as well.

Comment: Hey Vishal, this doesn't return any results.

Comment: Hi @yeniv, Sorry I didn't saw you were using postgresql. I have updated the query you can give it a try now. Also you can first try without adding the having clause to see what data is returned.

Comment: Nothing is returned, even without the having clause.

Comment: @yeniv can you share the output of this `Job.joins(:stacks).select("STRING_AGG(stacks.name) AS stack_name").group('stacks.job_id').first.attributes`

Comment: Sure thing! The error reads: 

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function string_agg(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT STRING_AGG(stacks.name) AS stack_name FROM "jobs" INN...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Seems like some value in `stacks.name` is other than string. `STRING_AGG` only works on string values. You can try this answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33717650

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
names = ['JavaScript', 'Python']
Job.where(id: 
  Stack.
    where(name: names).
    select(:job_id).
    group(:job_id).
    having("count(*) >= ?", names.size)
)
```

Comment: I gave it a try, David. It doesn't return any results.