# Postgres concatenation of a column for a given group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a Postgres DB with a `SHOWS` table that looks like this:

```
id      date        venue                       price  is_sold  ages    time    multi_day   pit
13      2016-01-02  924 Gilman Street, Berkeley $8      FALSE    a/a     7:30pm  FALSE       FALSE
```

I have a query that orders everything in this table by date (which is of `timestamptz` type):

`SELECT shows.* FROM shows ORDER BY date`

Right now, running this query with the [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library produces an array of objects that look like this:

```
[   
    { id: 1,
    date: Thu Oct 20 2016 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT),
    venue: 'Regency Ballroom, S.F.',
    price: null,
    is_sold: false,
    ages: 'a/a',
    time: null,
    multi_day: false,
    pit: false },
  { id: 2,
    date: Thu Oct 20 2016 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT),
    venue: 'Great American Music Hall.',
    price: null,
    is_sold: false,
    ages: 'a/a',
    time: null,
    multi_day: false,
    pit: false } ... ]
```

I want to return an array that groups this data by `date` column. Example output:

```
[ 
    {date: Thu Oct 20 2016 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT),
     shows: [1, 2]}, // or however this should be structured; I just want a way to get multiple show ids from a single date.
    ...
]
```

which I assume I could then INNER JOIN to get the rest of the show details that I need.

How do I adjust my query to return this sort of grouping?

Comment: Try read this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query It may help you...

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the question, use

```
SELECT date, string_agg(id, ', ') AS show_ids
FROM shows
GROUP BY date
```