# String concatenation in GroupBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, npgsql

This query below doesn't work because `String.Join` is not translatable.

PostgreSQL has the [string_agg(expression, delimiter)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43944/221683) feature though.

Is there anyway to use it from Linq?

```
var vwTourWithCategorieses = Context.Tours
                .Join(Context.TourCategories, t => t.TourId, tc => tc.TourId,
                    (t, tc) => new { t.TourId, t.Name, tc.CategoryId})
                .Join(Context.Categories, x => x.CategoryId, c => c.CategoryId,
                    (x, c) => new { x.TourId, TourName = x.Name, CategoryName = c.Name})
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.TourId, x.TourName },
                    (key, c) => new VwTourWithCategories
                    {
                        TourId = key.TourId,
                        Name = key.TourName,
                        Categories = string.Join(",", c.Select(i => i.CategoryName))
                    })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately `String.Join` is not supported by EF, but I think you could project the result that you expect using Linq to objects after you materialize your query:

```
var query= Context.Tours
            .Join(Context.TourCategories, t => t.TourId, tc => tc.TourId,
                (t, tc) => new { t.TourId, t.Name, tc.CategoryId})
            .Join(Context.Categories, x => x.CategoryId, c => c.CategoryId,
                (x, c) => new { x.TourId, TourName = x.Name, CategoryName = c.Name})
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.TourId, x.TourName }).ToList()


var result=query.Select( g=> new VwTourWithCategories
                {
                    TourId = g.Key.TourId,
                    Name = g.Key.TourName,
                    Categories = string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.CategoryName))
                });
```

If you want to see all the CLR methods that are supported, you can check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Update

Your query could be simpler if you use [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520(v=vs.110).aspx). I think that is a many to many relationship, so you could do something like this:

```
var query= Context.Tours.Select(t=> new 
                                    {
                                      t.TourId, 
                                      t.Name,
                                      CategoryNames = t.TourCategories.Select(tc=>tc.Category.Name)
                                    } 
                               ).ToList();

var result=query.Select( g=> new VwTourWithCategories
                {
                    TourId = g.Key.TourId,
                    Name = g.Key.TourName,
                    Categories = string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.CategoryName))                 
                });
```

Comment: That's returning much more data though. I think its better to fetch the tours and then fetch the relevant categories separately.

Comment: But why so you say is fetching more data that you expect? in the last join you re not projecting just three columns?Another question, are you using navigation properties to represent the relationships between your entities?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought your query had left my join intact. Had that been the case, then it would have returned the same tour data for every category assigned. That's why I figured it would be more data. I don't know how your database query gets translated to SQL.