# merge all rows columns into single column from joined table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to join a table which has multiple rows and need to merge one of the column from all the rows into single column.

```
select a.parent_id,a.parent_name,concat(b.child_name) from parent a 
join children b on (a.parent_id=b.parent_id);
```

This should return all the parent rows and each parent row should have all its children's.

i am thinking to group with parent_id but getting multiple records (one record per child). What logic i can implement here apart from grouping to get all child's for a parent in single row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

Comment: postgres 9.0 + string_agg() and group by

Comment: If i do group by with child_name, i am getting error as - column "a.parent_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: If i add parent_id,parent_name and child_name in group by clause, i am getting one row for each child.

Comment: child_name shouldn't go in the group by clause.  It is what you want to aggregate.  See my answer below.

Comment: Got it now, child_name should not be present in group by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT a.parent_id, a.parent_name, STRING_AGG(b.child_name, ',') as Children
FROM
    Parent a
    INNER JOIN children b
    ON a.Id = b.ParentId
GROUP BY
    a.parent_id
    ,a.parent_name
```