# How to fetch the ids in a column where multiple columns are repeated

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, postgresql-9.4

I have a table like the next:

```
 TABLE 1
 -------
 ID        Integer
 COLUMN_1  Text
 COLUMN_2  Text
 COLUMN_3  Integer
```

How could I fetch the ids in which the combination of `COLUMN_1` , `COLUMN_2` and `COLUMN_3` are repetead in the same column?

I count the columns repeated grouping it like next:

```
select  column_1, column_2, column_3, count(*) from table_ 1 group by icolumn_1, column_2, column_3;
```

But what I'm looking for is how to also get the Ids.

---

#### Example

So if I have the next data:

```
ID  | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3
1   |     BLUE |  FISH    |  SEA
2   |     BLUE |  FISH    |  SEA
3   |     BLUE |  FISH    |  RIVER
```

I'm looking for a result like next:

```
 IDs Repeated |  COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 | COLUMN_3 | COUNT
     1, 2     |     BLUE  |  FISH    |    SEA   |   2
       3      |     BLUE  |  FISH    |    RIVER |   1
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, the following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT string_agg(id::varchar, ', ') AS "IDs Repeated",
  column_1, column_2, column_3, COUNT(*)
FROM p
GROUP BY column_1, column_2, column_3;
```

(I corrected what I believe was a typo in your result column name).

However, the result is not in first normal form. You might be interested by the following query:

```
SELECT id, column_1, column_2, column_3, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY column_1, column_2, column_3)
FROM p;

 id | column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | count 
----+----------+----------+----------+-------
  3 | BLUE     | FISH     | RIVER    |     1
  1 | BLUE     | FISH     | SEA      |     2
  2 | BLUE     | FISH     | SEA      |     2
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, that what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with an aggregate function [string_agg(expression, delimiter)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE).
There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query). It has an answer with examples.

Comment: Yes and I know it, but how to combine both groups id group and columns 1, 2 and 3 group?

Answer (score 1):

Check This.

```
        SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(id), ',') as "IDs Repetead",
        COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3,count(id) as "COUNT" 
        FROM temp
        GROUP BY COLUMN_1,COLUMN_3,COLUMN_2
        order by  "IDs Repetead"
```

Comment: `array_to_string(array_agg(id), ',')` can be simplified to `string_agg(id::text, ','))`

Comment: Yes .. We can also use this.