# How to create group and associate values in list?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table in PostgreSQL:

```
id  related
1     FT5G
2     FT5G
5     RT5G
16     B5
8    RT5G
```

I want to group by `related` and then get in one column list of all it's `id`s.
Expected result is:

```
related  ids
FT5G      1,2
RT5G      5,8
B5        16
```

I know it should be:

```
select   ?
from tabl
group by related
```

This will give the groups, but I don't know how to specify the `id`s in list for each group.

Comment: change your `SELECT` to : `SELECT related, string_agg(id, ',') as ids`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)