# How to use Postgres string_agg function on multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql

So I have a 3 tables that I select from to create a selection that looks like this:

[image]

The SQL statement used to get this selection (from 3 tables):

```
SELECT games.title as title, taggings.taggable_id as game_id, tags.name as category, tags.id
    FROM taggings, tags, games
    WHERE taggings.tag_id = tags.id and games.id = taggings.taggable_id
```

What I want to do is to make the selection combine all the categories fields. So there would only be one row for superorbit.io and it would contain a category field with "2d Shooter, Asteroids, Free For All, etc". Very much like what this guy was trying to do:
[How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

I'm trying to do that exact same thing, but with little luck. I think the major difference between my case is and his is that I'm working with 3 tables here (taggings, tags and games). Here's the query that I have so far (using the string_agg function) but it doesn't seem to concatenate the categories like you would expect it to. In fact, the results look almost the same as the first code.

```
  SELECT games.title as title, taggings.taggable_id as game_id, string_agg(tags.name, ', ') , tags.id
    FROM taggings, tags, games
    WHERE taggings.tag_id = tags.id and games.id = taggings.taggable_id  GROUP BY tags.name,games.title,taggings.taggable_id,tags.id
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using Postgres 9.6.7.

Comment: You’re telling the database to group by tag names so they will be treated separately. Remove that column from grouping since you’re aggregating it

Comment: Tried that. results are the same. Also tried removing GROUP BY altogether but i get an error: ERROR:  column "games.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Also remove tags.id from results and group by

Comment: when i do that, it shows a single category in each row (i.e. not concated like "2d Shooter, Asteroids, Free For All, etc")

Comment: nvm my last comment, i re-read your last comments and reconstructed the SQL statements properly. It works!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sami, was able to get the results I wanted with the following query:

```
  SELECT games.title as title, taggings.taggable_id as game_id, string_agg(tags.name, ', ')
    FROM taggings, tags, games
    WHERE taggings.tag_id = tags.id and games.id = taggings.taggable_id  GROUP BY games.title,taggings.taggable_id
```