# How to aggregate multiple rows in a field in a joined aggregated query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
id | color | qty
---|-------|-----
1  | red   | 10
2  | green | 20
3  | blue  | 50
```

Table 2:

```
id | shade  
---|-------
1  | light
1  | dark   
2  | light
3  | light
3  | dark
```

How can I write a query that joins the two tables and returns the shades as a comma delimited string i.e.

```
1 | red   | light, dark | 10
2 | green | light       | 20
3 | blue  | light, dark | 50
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using version 9.0 or higher, you can use an aggregated query with « string_agg » :

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.color,
    string_agg(t2.shade, ', ')
    t1.quantity
FROM
    table1 as t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY
    t1.id,
    t1.color,
    t1.quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if your version below 9.0 you can try this.

```
select 
  t1.id,
  t1.color,
  array_to_string(array_agg(t2.shade), ','),
  t1.qty
from
  tbl1 as t1
  inner join tbl2 as t2 on t2.id = t1.id
group by
  t1.id,
  t1.color,
  t1.qty
order by
  t1.id
```

You can check here for [*Demo*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=4da21b01798454e7df90e1c6e7dd114e)